# Does it make sense to have indices and normals in VBOs

Tags: opengl, vbo, normals

I am writing a plugin which renders some meshes in OpenGL.

I have a Vertices array in a VBO and an Indices array in another VBO. I now want to store Normals. As a vertex, being shared between multiple faces, has different normals, it seems that I must replicate vertices multiples times, and therefore lose the use of indices.

As an example, to store a cube with vertices and indices, I need 8 vertices and 24 indices (4 per face). However if I want to store normals, do I need to store 24 vertices (8 having each 3 faces), 24 indices (all sequential) and 24 normals ?

Do I see it right, and therefore Indices become useless, or is there a way to not duplicate vertices and anyway have multiple normals per vertex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so easy. Indices have a great feature called a *primitive restart index*. It lets you describe your shape with, e.g. `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, thus using less indices for the same mesh. Further, smooth parts of your model share some vertices, and usually you have more shared data than duplicated vertices, so in the end it's a net win.

Consider now your cube example. Let `I` be the size of the index type and `V` be the size of the vertex data. Lets take `I = sizeof(uint) = 4` and `V = 3*sizeof(float) + 4*sizeof(byte) = 16` (three floats for position and a low-precision normal).

`glDrawArrays` with `GL_TRIANGLES` needs two triangles per face, that is `2*3*6*V = 512` bytes.

`glDrawElements` with `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` needs four indices per face plus a restart index, that is `5*6*I = 120` bytes, and four vertices per face, which is `4*6*V = 384` bytes. That is 504 bytes in total.

As you see even with that cube example and some conservative type choices the indexed approach still wins on the memory footprint. In reality you're able to use `short` indices and might need higher precision normal, which will bias even more towards the indexed approach.

Comment: Thanks. In the VBO/VAO/Indices world, are we talking about 1 Normal per Vertex or 1 Normal per Index ?

Comment: Per vertex. Normals are vertex attributes like any other vertex attribute, including position, texcoordinates, diffuse color, YOU name it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to duplicate only the sharp edge vertexes but meshes have usually many other vertexes that do not need to be duplicated (like curvature surfaces).

So Indices does not loss their purpose. 8 vertex Cube is just a wrong example .... Try to make a cube with regular vertex coverage lets say `4x4 = 16` vertexes per face and suddenly you need to duplicate only the edge vertexes... The ratio between edge and inner vertexes is usually in favor for the inner vertexes